# VBA Excel textbox and text properties don't work

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to customize my textbox a bit by adding the text on the top and make the background grey. Unfortunately with the following code it fail to response.

```
    With Navshp
    .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = UCase("Navigation")
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.size = 17
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
    .TextFrame.AutoSize = False
    .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.size = 22
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = True
    .BackColor = RGB(185, 185, 185)
     End With
```

Is there any way of customizing this textbox?

[image]

Comment: What textbox? That appears to be a set of buttons.

Comment: You need to clarify that you are working with the Text within a shape, not a TextBox control. How have you initialised `Navshp`?

Comment: In Excel TextFrame2 has TextRange object

Comment: The textbox is just below the buttons. You can see this white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say textbox I take it you mean the textbox shape on a sheet, rather than a textbox on a userform.
i.e.  *Insert > Shapes > Basic Shapes > Text Box*

```
Sub Test()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("NavShp")
    
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "NAVIGATION"
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 17
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
        .TextFrame2.AutoSize = False
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(185, 185, 185)
        
     End With
End Sub
```

Note sure why you use `UCase("Navigation")` instead of just `NAVIGATION`.
I've also not added these three lines as they just change the text that  you've already changed...

```
.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.size = 22
.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = True
```